# DataGridView playing stubborn. It just wouldn't bind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, data-binding, datagridview

I have one stubborn data grid view is refusing to display the bound data.
i placed a grid view named exhibitgridview and set its datasource to none. then i added a standalone data source that can return columns into the grid but first there data displayed in the grid would be based on a what gets selected from a dropdown list. check it out from the picture below. [image]

So basically some item is selected from the dropdown list next to the caseid label and the grid displays values accordingly... AS such i needed a selectedIndexchanged method so i had this in my page.cs

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateDataSet();

            caseID = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.Trim();

        DataView exhibitDataView = new DataView(exhibitDataSet.Tables[0]);
        exhibitDataView.RowFilter = "FilingID = '" + caseID + "' ";
        ExhibitGridView.DataSource = exhibitDataView;
        ExhibitGridView.DataBind();
    }
    private void CreateDataSet()
    {
        exhibitConnection.ConnectionString =
        ExhibitListSqlDataSource.ConnectionString;
        exhibitSqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new
        SqlCommand(ExhibitListSqlDataSource.SelectCommand, exhibitConnection);
        exhibitSqlDataAdapter.Fill(exhibitDataSet);
    }
```

The code runs sweet...I inserted a breakpoint as to ensure some data is actually returned for binding and there is...you can see that from the screen shot below:
[image]

that was until (ExhibitGridView.DataBind()). So when i run the next block, i expect the data to bind and display in the browser but for some unknown reason the gridview is acting stubborn. i tried specifying the datasource directly and it displays successfully at pageload but otherwise it wouldn't respond.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe you need to supply your DataAdapter with the parameters that you are supplying your select statement with.  Take a look.

I have given you an example from my code which uses OleDB (I have removed all the open / close connection for ease of reading).  They are VERY similar.

```
SqlCmd = "select * from App_Details WHERE App_Name LIKE @Var";

aCommand = new OleDbCommand(SqlCmd, aConnection);
aCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Var", value);

OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SqlCmd, aConnection);
OleDbCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

// Now I do not see this part in your code right before you bind your data
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Var", value);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(table);
dgvSearchApp.DataSource = table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure about Post Back events. Maybe the page is doing two post backs.